# Installing JQt IDE for the J language, getting error

Tags: linux, qt, installation, j

I've been following the instructions here:

http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/System/Installation/Linux

to install J on an Ubuntu, new computer with everything updated.  I have managed to follow all of the instructions up to the point where I install a JQt IDE

http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Guides/Qt_IDE/Install

When I search the various file paths listed at the first like, like `/usr/bin`, I don't see any `jqt.sh` nor do I know which one is "the J install directory" since I only downloaded the .deb file to my downloads folder and then it installed other files in other places.

When I try to run

```
sudo jqt
```

I get

```
"/usr/bin/libjqt.so"
"could not resolve: state_run:

Cannot load library /usr/bin/libjqt.so: (libQt5WebSockets.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
```

Comment: You may have more support by subscribing to the J general forum, where the developers of the language are pretty good about supporting the variety of platforms that run J.  More info at http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/System/Forums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the `libQt5WebSockets.so.5` package , `sudo apt-get install libqt5websockets5`

Comment: Done, now it gives the error `Load library /usr/bin/libj.so failed.` I checked `/usr/bin` and it doesn't have the file.  I think before doing this I had `libj.so` in `/usr/lib` but it's not there anymore either.  Do I need to re-install J at this point?

Comment: I did, the .so file is in my `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` folder.  Dumb question I'm sure, but I want to check that moving the file from there to `/usr/bin` won't hurt anything and is the right thing to do?

Comment: Went ahead and tried, it got a window to pop up but in the terminal it says `j first line error: "25"` and the window is titled "Term" and comes up with the error in it:  `file name error` `0!:0 y`.

Comment: no should not do that since the file is linked to some contents in `x86_64-linux-gnu` try to link `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/  /usr/bin/jconsole`

Comment: So I moved the files back and looked up a resource on how to mess with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, typed into the terminal `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/bin/ijconsole:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" thinking that maybe you had a typo in what you wrote (`bini`) and thinking you separate things with a colon not a space (?).  When I issue `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` it tells me `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/bin/ijconsole:`.  When I run `sudo jqt` I get the same error.

Comment: Retried it so that `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` returns `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/bin/ijconsole:` and still the same error.

Comment: Try `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libj.so.8.05 /usr/bin/libj.so`

Comment: It again complains `j first line error: "25"` and pops a window with the same error as before.

Comment: At this point I might ought to start a new question since the main question here has been successfully answered and the problem I'm facing now seems new.

Comment: Try to do `jconsole install 'qtide'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131994/discussion-between-arduino-sentinel-and-addem).

Answer (score -1):

```
mv /usr/bin/libjqt.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

did solve this issue for me.

Comment: Tried it, got this error:  `appmenu-qt: registerWindow 206 "&File"
...
void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "&Test" under id 60
...
Load library libj.so.8.05 failed.` where the `...` indicates a bunch of other messages similarly styled.

Comment: Why would there be a `*.so` file under `/usr/bin`?