# After installing J, I get several error messages about DBusMenuExporterPrivate

Tags: linux, j

I have installed J, in fact in two ways, one by following the official instructions in their guide.  However, that resulted in error messages as I detail in this question: [Installing JQt IDE for the J language, getting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41409128/installing-jqt-ide-for-the-j-language-getting-error/41409445?noredirect=1#comment70029436_41409445)

I have now also installed J using the instructions in the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/705338/install-j-on-ubuntu

And this works.  But when I run `jqt` I get the errors

```
void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "&Test" under id 50 
void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "&Clipboard" under id 48 
void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "Run &Project" under id 51 
void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "&Vocabulary" under id 60 
void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "&NuVoc" under id 63 
void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "&Context Sensitive" under id 61 
void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "&NuVoc Context Sensitive" under id 64
```

and a window pops up with the error message

```
|file name error
|       0!:0 y
```

If I navigate to `~/j64-803` and run `bash jqt.sh` I get the same error messages in the terminal but the window that pops up has no errors.

Answer (score 3):

I don't recall seeing that error message before or your earlier posts to the J forum, but in any case it looks like you are trying to install j803, whereas it would be better to install the current version, j805.

See instructions at code.jsoftware.com/wiki/System/Installation.

If you still have problems, please use the J forums, see code.jsoftware.com/wiki/System/Forums.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I got rid of everything j803 and walked back through all the installation instructions (both on the website and in that other overflow answer I found) and get the same errors.  Just posted a question to the forums.

Comment: You may want to check that your question is actually getting through (I haven't seen it). If the message is being bounced this may provide a remedy http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/System/Forums#Bounces  Also, forum members have suggested that these may be considered warnings rather than errors, but that may become apparent after a solution is found. I would help you myself, but I am not knowledgable about your platform.

Comment: @bob I see, I didn't realize I had to be subscribed to the forum in order to post a message, I thought you just send a message to general and it gets posted.  I've subscribed and will try again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Bill Lam has replied on the J General forum:

"There was a bug in base library for installing jqt from linux
deb.  An updated version of base library has been release and
the linux installation wiki page also revised.  Hopefully this
can solve his problem."

Perhaps, give it another try and see if it works now. I still haven't seen your question show up on the J forums, so going forward that may be something that you may want to look into. Let us know if the updated package works so that Stack Overflow people can know that the question has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As I posted as a comment on an earlier question, you may have more success by subscribing to the J general forum, where the developers of the language are pretty good about supporting the variety of platforms that run J. More info at [code.jsoftware.com/wiki/System/Forums](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/System/Forums)   Then if you get the answer you want you can post the solution here to support others on StackOverflow.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that a while ago and never got a response.

Comment: You may want to check that your message got through to the forum. In the meantime, chris has some suggestions below.